# Error when comparing float and element array of float

Tags: c

So I have a to create a program that creates an array and adds 6 grades to it, then it has to calculate the average in a different function, and then check what grades are above the average.
It all worked until this little operation started to throw an error like such: 
main.c:29:18: error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'float (*)(float *)' and 'float')

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float media(float grades[]){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        sum += grades[i];
    }
    float media = sum/6;
    printf("A media é %f", media);
    return media;
}

int acimamedia(float media(float grades[]), float vetor[], int x){
    for(int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
        float z = vetor[i];   
        if(media < z){       // <<<<<<<<<<<<< [Error here]
            x += 1;
        }
    }
 return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float grades[6];
    int acimadamedia;

    printf("As notas sao: \n");
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        grades[i] = rand()%100;
        printf("Nota [%d] -- %f",i , grades[i]);
    }
    printf("Existem %d notas acima da media.", acimadamedia());
```

Comment: Is this your real code? `int acimamedia(float media(float grades[]), float vetor[], int x)`?

Comment: yes it is, is it that flawed??

Comment: This should be a compile error: `float media(float grades[])`

Comment: it didn't claim it to be an error so i just moved on, what change should I do to it??

Comment: `acimamedia` isn't being called anyplace.  Where do you plan on calling it, and how exactly?

Comment: It should be called to the last printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

media is a function declaration:

```
float media(float grades[])
```

and z is a single float value

so you are trying to compare a function pointer to a float hence the error is exactly as what it says:

```
error: invalid operands to binary < (have 'float (*)(float *)' and 'float')
```

In addition your call of acimadamedia() is trying to treat an integer as a function.

If I kind of understand what you are trying to do and do the minimum of changes to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float media(float grades[]){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    sum += grades[i];
  }
  float media = sum/6;
  printf("A media é %f\n", media);
  return media;
}

int acimamedia(float media(float grades[]), float vetor[]){
  int x = 0;
  float avg = media(vetor);
  for(int i = 0; i < 6;i++){
    float z = vetor[i];
    if(avg < z){
        x += 1;
    }
  }
  return x;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  float grades[6];
  int acimadamedia;

  printf("As notas sao: \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    grades[i] = rand()%100;
    printf("Nota [%d] -- %f\n",i , grades[i]);
  }
  acimadamedia = acimamedia(&media, grades);
  printf("Existem %d notas acima da media.\n", acimadamedia);
  return 0;
}
```

Will show the grades, the avg grade and the number of grades above the average

the acimamedia function for passing a function usally is specified as:

```
 int acimamedia(float (*media)(float grades[]), float vetor[])
```

Comment: I thought I function pointer had to take this form: `float (*media)(float grades[])`

Comment: you still can not compare a function pointer to a float which is the error it is having, and yes usually you would declare it as you said, however some compilers allow weird stuff, so may not have shown an error.

Comment: This is an execise on using functions as parameters so i tried to do like it shows and i find no other way to compare those two values without the error

Comment: but you don't want to compare a function pointer to a float - perhaps you want to compare the result of the function to it ?

Comment: Yes lostbard the result of the function is what i need to compare

Comment: so what is being input to the acimamedia function? as its not being called from main.